# Force request client certificate in MVC5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ssl-certificate

I have a MVC5 web application with C #, js, Ajax and bootstrap in which I limit the access by digital certificate request to the client. When a client enters the SSL site a certificate is requested so you can enter (and then, inside, I can determine whether or not you can enter the App.), or if there is no client certificate, I have placed a custom error page OUT of the website, at Server level, responding to error 403.7 to indicate that there is no certificate.

Up to here, everything is correct and working.

My application, at the moment, is a single view that loads and recharges everything via Ajax. No new get requests to change from one view to another. In one operation, using a Bootstrap modal message, I ask for some data and I need that slicking the "send button", the client certificate must be requested AGAIN, to make sure that the user is who he says to be, although it is already inside the application.

As more attempts I make and more ideas I try, I am absolutely unable to make me ask for the certificate again.

Is there any way to do it? (even if I have to change everything)

And on the other hand but without leaving the subject ... is there any way to "remove" by code from the browser cache the info of the selected certificate, so that if I put buttons "Log in" and "Log out", after clicking login out I delete the information and when I click log in button again, to force to ask for the client certificate again (It would be enought for me to force him to ask for the client certificate, but I do not care if the client certificate is not physically removed from memory).

Thank you!

Comment: Great question! See this: https://security.stackexchange.com/a/35951 - therefore, my grok on it is that the pop up is a browser (native) function and you can't force that. If your server requests a client cert and then responds, then the browser _did_ send the (previously chosen) cert (whether or not it was via AJAX)